# Dragging UIButtons in UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a scrollview in my Main view and I have three subviews on my scrollview. And I have UIButtons in all my subviews.

Now, I want to drag those buttons from one subview to another subview (while dragging the buttons, the scrollview should not scroll).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not completely sure if this snippet works for this particular case (an UIControl inside a UIScrollView), but my understanding of UIResponder chain suggests me that it should :)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { // or wherever you initialize your things
    ...
    // Add swipe event to UIButton so it will capture swipe intents
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGR = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    [panGR addTarget:self action:@selector(panEvent:)];
    [button addGestureRecognizer:panGR];
    [panGR release];
}

- (void)panEvent:(id)sender {
    button.center = [sender locationInView:self.view];
}
```

If this works (can't test it right now, but it did work for me in a similar situation), then you should add more code to handle the drag & drop related events (maybe disable Clip Subviews option in the UIScrollView, add the button to the new superview if the location intersects with the CGRect of the destination, return the button to the original location if it doesn't, etc).

So, what's happening in those lines? When you begin touching the UIButton, the order doesn't get to the UIScrollView because the event could follow as a touch event (handled by the UIButton), or as a pan event (handled by the UIScrollView). When you move your finger, the event is dismissed by the UIButton's responder because there's no [Gesture Recognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that knows how to proceed if the finger is moved.

But when you add a Gesture Recognizer to the UIButton who actually knows what to do when the finger is moved, everything is different: the UIButton will not dismiss the event, and the UIScrollView will never realize that there was a touch moving over it.

I hope my explanation is accurate and comprensible enough. Let me know if a) it doesn't work or b) there's something unclear.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank u so much for your kind help.Button moving finely.At the same time,

I just want to assign exact point to button.center,In order to perform accurate move,i need to use touchesBegan,touchesMoved,touchesEnded.While using this method,touch fuctionality is not working.....

How to do it?

Comment: When start using touchesBegan, Moved and Ended you dismiss all the gestures and responder chains functionality. With UIPanGestureRecognizer you can access to the exact location of the touch using locationInView, that returns you a CGPoint relative to the view that you pass as parameter (the main view in this case). Doesn't fit in your case?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
       if (allowAppDrag && [gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        return NO;
    }

   return YES;
}
```